# comma-delimited lists with CSS—I want an Oxford Comma!

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to extend an [old CSS trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517220/how-to-style-unordered-lists-in-css-as-comma-separated-text) to new lengths, taking into account the sinister future of [the Oxford Comma](http://www.salon.com/books/feature/2011/06/30/death_of_the_serial_oxford_comma/index.html). I like the Oxford Comma. I want my inline lists to use it. That is,

I would like this html

```
<ul id="taglist">
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li>banana</li>
</ul>
```

to show up as this:

```
apple, orange, & banana
```

---

Now, I can get it to show up as

```
apple, orange & banana
```

using this CSS:

```
#taglist {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

#taglist li {
  display: inline;
}

#taglist li:after {
  content: ", ";
}

#taglist li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}

#taglist li:nth-last-child(2):after {
  content: " & ";
}
```

but the ***problem***, you see, is that we can't simply change that last statement to `content: ", & "` because lists with only ***two*** items will look stupid. Like

```
I like to eat apples, & bananas
```

---

So for a list of 3 or more, I want a comma after the second-to-last element. For lists of two, I want no comma.

Comment: did you try your code with two elements? It is working

Comment: It works, but it doesn't have the Oxford comma.

Comment: +1 for the Oxford comma

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I added this extra rule, it appears to do what you want:

```
#taglist li:nth-last-child(3) ~ li:nth-last-child(2):after {
  content: ", & ";
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about the [General Sibling Combinator](http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-general-sibling-combinator-in-action)! This can also be accomplished with the Adjacent Sibling Combinator with less characters, using `#taglist li:nth-last-child(3) + li:after`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to leave comments yet, but I have something to share that I think is helpful.

I made a JSfiddle demo of chadoh's improved version of [Taze T. Schnitzel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587807/comma-delimited-lists-with-cssi-want-an-oxford-comma/6587877#6587877). I have also included and commented-out Taze's original answer and chadoh's first attempt at an answer. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u7rzA/