# Using comma as list separator with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to create a comma-separated list of items:

```
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
      <b ng-repeat="email in friend.email">{{email}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</b>...
  </li>
```

According to the AngularJS documentation, no control flow statements is allowed in expressions. This is why my `{{$last ? '' : ', '}}` does not work.

Is there an alternative way to create comma-separated lists?

**EDIT 1**
is there something simpler than:

```
<span ng-show="!$last">, </span>
```

Comment: You can always use CSS to format lists in this way (then you don't need to modify HTML when your boss wants them on separate lines etc) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517220/how-to-style-unordered-lists-in-css-as-comma-separated-text

Answer (score 342, accepted):

You could do it this way:

`<b ng-repeat="email in friend.email">{{email}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</b>`

..But I like Philipp's answer :-)

Comment: Shouldn't `($last && '' || ', ')` always yield `', '`?

Comment: LIke okm above, I couldn't get angular to properly evaluate $last to true or false within a template. I used this: `{{{true: '', false: ', '}[$last]}}`. This technique is more flexible than using `.join` because it allows the elements in the list to each be members of an array, like: `<b ng-repeat="friend in friends">{{friend.email}}{{{true: '', false: ', '}[$last]}}</b>`

Comment: Updated to use ternary operators

Comment: How can i insert and in the printed array so that my array looks like this : John, Mike and Nil. How to get this format without using directive.

Comment: I'm using this approach since it allows me to use a filter on each value in the list.

Comment: I like this one because it works great for iterating over objects as well...thx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 232):

Just use Javascript's built-in [`join(separator)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function for arrays:

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
  <b>{{friend.email.join(', ')}}</b>...
</li>
```

Comment: If you want HTML-ish separators it's probably time to a write [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). You could also put HTML into `join()` and disable HTML escaping, but there's a special place in hell for that ;)

Comment: Nice, I didn't even think about using it this way.

Comment: @DavidKEgghead I beg to differ, http://jsfiddle.net/wuZRA/. How does it not work for you?

Comment: @PhilippReichart sorry for the delay. Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Sek8F/ -- looks like you are targeting a string where as I am referring to an object.

Answer (score 101):

Also:

```
angular.module('App.filters', [])
    .filter('joinBy', function () {
        return function (input,delimiter) {
            return (input || []).join(delimiter || ',');
        };
    });
```

And in template:

```
{{ itemsArray | joinBy:',' }}
```

Comment: This answer shows "angular way" and should be marked as the best.

Comment: Why not save six lines and just do `{{ itemsArray.join(', ') }}`?

Comment: I'm not sure re-writing JavaScript core functions in AngularJS is really "the Angular way"...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16673793/1483977) answer shows how Angular can add value for arrays of objects

Answer (score 42):

```css
.list-comma::before {
  content: ',';
}
.list-comma:first-child::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<span class="list-comma" ng-repeat="destination in destinations">
                            {{destination.name}}
                        </span>
```

Comment: This seems to the most "semantic" way, as the choice of using a comma-separated list is entirely about presentation. It could just as well have been a sublist.

Comment: This was the first solution that came to my mind. Less reliant on JavaScript.

Answer (score 10):

You can use CSS to fix it too

```
<div class="some-container">
[ <span ng-repeat="something in somethings">{{something}}<span class="list-comma">, </span></span> ]
</div>

.some-container span:last-child .list-comma{
    display: none;
}
```

But Andy Joslin's answer is best

Edit: I changed my mind I had to do this recently and I ended up going with a join filter.

Comment: I'd go for a custom filter too, but I like your idea :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it's better to use `ng-if`. `ng-show` creates an element in the `dom` and sets it's `display:none`.  The more `dom` elements you have the more resource hungry your app becomes, and on devices with lower resources the less `dom` elements the better.

TBH `<span ng-if="!$last">, </span>` seems like a great way to do it.  It's simple.

Comment: I like this approach, as it's simple and still supports html based separators. Thanks @the7erm!

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is quite old and AngularJS had had time to evolve since then, this can now be easily achieved using:

`<li ng-repeat="record in records" ng-bind="record + ($last ? '' : ', ')"></li>`.

**Note that I'm using `ngBind` instead of interpolation `{{ }}` as it's much more performant:** `ngBind`  will only run when the passed value does actually change. The brackets `{{ }}`, on the other hand, will be dirty checked and refreshed in every $digest, even if it's not necessary. Source: [here](https://ng-perf.com/2014/10/30/tip-4-ng-bind-is-faster-than-expression-bind-and-one-time-bind/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125872/angularjs-why-ng-bind-is-better-than-in-angular/16126174#answer-23382400) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097006/angularjs-why-is-ng-bind-faster-than-expressions#answer-27097165).

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.records = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    }
  ]);
```

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="record in records" ng-bind="record + ($last ? '' : ', ')"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On a final note, all of the solutions here work and are valid to this day. I'm really found to those which involve CSS as this is more of a presentation issue.

Answer (score 1):

I like simbu's approach, but I ain't comfortable to use first-child or last-child. Instead I only modify the content of a repeating list-comma class.

```css
.list-comma + .list-comma::before {
    content: ', ';
}
```

```html
<span class="list-comma" ng-repeat="destination in destinations">
    {{destination.name}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-show to limit the values, the `{{$last ? '' : ', '}}` won`t work since it will still take into consideration all the values.Example

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records" ng-show="x.email == 1">{{x}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</div>

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {"email": "1"},
    {"email": "1"},
    {"email": "2"},
    {"email": "3"}
  ]
});
```

[Results in adding a comma after the "last" value](https://jsfiddle.net/pnejz3w9/1/),since with ng-show it still takes into consideration all 4 values

```
{"email":"1"},
{"email":"1"},
```

[One solution is to add a filter](https://jsfiddle.net/pnejz3w9/8/) directly into ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records | filter: { email : '1' } ">{{x}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</div>
```

Results

```
{"email":"1"},
{"email":"1"}
```

Comment: Any suggestion on how to solve this issue the same way in Angular 2 without creating a custom pipe?