# List array objects properties sepatated with ,

Tags: angularjs

I have a array of objects with property 'name'.

```
<script>
function FriendsCtrl($scope) {
$scope.friends = [{
    email: ['abc', 'def'],
    name: "i'm noob"
}, {
    email: ['ghi', 'jkl'],
     name: "me 2"
},
{
    email: ['ghi', 'jkl'],
     name: "and me!"
}];
}
</script>
```

I want to list as string all names inside a div, separated with ','
I managed to do it this way, using underscore:

```
<span ng-repeat="email in friends">{{email.name}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</span>
```

Rez:

```
i'm noob, me 2, and me!
```

How to solve this problem using angular way?

Thanks!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UJEnt/

Comment: Already answered, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540157/using-comma-as-list-separator-with-angularjs

Comment: that's pretty angular-ish to me, what exactly do you mean by using the angular way?

Comment: Fedaykin: i meant something like Joseph answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to create this CSV like behavior, you can use a custom `filter` ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter))

**http://jsfiddle.net/c8DKB/3/**

**csv filter**

```
myApp.filter('csv', function() {
    return function(values, property_name) {
        var result = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            var value = values[i];
            if (property_name) {
                value = value[property_name];
            }
            result += value;
            if (i + 1 != values.length) {
                result += ',';
            }
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

**usage**

`friends` is the data source and `name` is the property

```
<div>{{friends | csv:'name'}}</div>
```

you can also use it without specifying property name (if you are dealing with a string array)

```
<div>{{another_string_array | csv}}</div>
```

**result**

**http://jsfiddle.net/c8DKB/3/**

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
angular.module('foo').filter('concat', function(input, field) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0, ii = input.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        result.push(input[i][field]);
    }

    return result.join(', ');
});
```

HTML:

```
<span>{{ friends | concat:'name' }}</span>
```