# AngularJS - Why is ng-bind faster than expressions?

Tags: angularjs, performance, ng-bind

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16125872/2317532) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23382400/2317532), it seems that using expressions will cause the value to be evaluated from scratch every time. But I've searched the documentation and tutorials, and I haven't found a reference for this statement.

In my mind, both are wrapped in a `$watch()` and so when the `$digest()` cycle runs it will see whether the value inside `ng-bind` or `{{}}` has changed.

**On performance, why is `ng-bind` better than `{{}}` as has been suggested, and where's the reference?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Details like this aren't always available in the documentation - you have to read the source. I took a peek and it seems that (as of 2014-11-24) they both work in a very similar way. Both cause a single directive to be instantiated to change the value when needed (the curly interpolation directive is generated on the fly).

Both directives evaluate the expressions involved on every `$digest` just like everything else. The main difference is that while ng-bind doesn't do any further processing on the value, with curlies, the entire interpolated text is recalculated on every digest. Essentially a string is built using [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) and that is compared with the previous value (this happens within the bowels of `$digest`). Neither way will update the DOM if the value (either the plain value with `ng-bind` or the interpolated result with curlies) hasn't changed.

To me the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126174/227267) on that question is a more compelling reason to use `ng-bind`, i.e. you can use it to prevent a visible flash of the template tags before Angular loads and compiles them, without resorting to hacks like ng-cloak.

Depending on variables there may also be cases where curly interpolation is actually *more* performant. One situation I can think of is when using ng-bind instead of interpolation requires you to create a lot of otherwise redundant `<span>` elements, and that tips the scales in the other direction. An interpolation expression also causes a single watcher to be created for the entire string independent of how many variables you use, as opposed to ng-bind which creates one watcher for each instance.

But as always, don't optimize for performance early, and if you do, profile to find out which part really matters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...after reading a bit more I can understand your answer now. However, I don't understanding how Angular can see if a value has changed without processing it first...

Comment: Or do you mean expression 1) evaluate the value 2) check the value against the last 3) if different use new value........and with ng-bind it's 1) use the new value

Comment: @dayuloli: The expressions are always evaluated and neither way will change the DOM if there's no need to. I updated my answer slightly to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it did help! I'll read about interpolate a bit more to really understand it fully. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The major difference between ng-bind and {{}} is that ng-bind creates a watcher for variable passed to it(i.e. name as in above example), while curly brackets({{}}) will (store the entire expression in memory i.e. }perform dirty-checking and refreshing the expression in every digest cycle even if it is not required.
ng-bind will only apply when the value passed is changing actually.
for more details refer below link:
http://www.ufthelp.com/2015/11/difference-between-and-ng-bind-in.html