# Get Unknown Provider Error trying to use $cookies

Tags: angularjs, cookies

in my Angular-App I try to use cookies to store some values. But I keep getting

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider
>
> Unknown provider: $cookiesProvider <- $cookies <- setlistCtrl

In my html-file, I reference angular-cookies:

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/setlist/setlistCtrl.js"></script>
```

In the app.js, I create the module and reference **ngCookies**

```
(function () {
    myModule = angular.module('myAngularApplication', ['ngCookies']);
}());
```

In the controller in setlistCtrl.js, I inject **$cookies**

```
(function () {
    var setlistCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $cookies) {
        var that = this;
        ...


    angular.module('myAngularApplication').controller('setlistCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "$cookies", setlistCtrl]);
  }

}());
```

I use Visual Studio 2013 and the AngularJS 1.4.3 packet installed via NuGet.

Any idea, what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: Did you check that the angular-cookies version you have lines up with 1.4.3?

Comment: Yap, it's "@license AngularJS v1.4.3" in the angular-cookies.js

Comment: How embarrassing. Here's my next code line ...

angular.module('poModule', []).filter('arrayToList', function () { ...

Looks like I redefined/override the module with module('poModule', []) ...

Comment: Ha ha, so a piece of code we couldn't even see in the question? :) Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not within the code but with one of the next lines.

Instead of using the getter

```
angular.module('poModule').filter(...
```

I used the setter

```
angular.module('poModule', []).filter(...
```

Copy'n'paste without exactly knowing what you do is quite dangerous, especially when the developement system doesn't protect you from common pitfalls. I got the code from here: [Angular JS Display String Array From Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506611/angular-js-display-string-array-from-json)