# Using *ngFor to display string values from array

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an array which is created from splitting a string using `str.split()` and this creates an array and it looks like this:

```
var array = [
  "TEXT1,1234,4321,9876",
  "TEXT2,2345,5432",
  "TEXT3,6543,3456"
]
```

I want to be able to display this information in a table using `*ngFor`.

I have tried this (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053860/using-comma-as-a-list-separator-in-angular-2)):

```
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let info of array">{{info.join(",")}}</td>
</tr>
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.join is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]
```

The table should look like this:

```
TITLE | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3
--------------------------------
TEXT1 | 1234   | 4321   | 9876
--------------------------------
TEXT2 | 2345   | 5432   |
--------------------------------
TEXT3 | 6543   | 3456   |
```

How do I achieve this table?

Comment: `info`contain string - `"TEXT1,1234,4321,9876"` and is not an array. So, join will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make array from string with `,` delimiters use [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of array">
  <td *ngFor="let info of row.split(',')">{{info}}</td>
</tr>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/1jGvRton0xtmu9VbUuEK)**

Answer (score 0):

You will need two `*ngFor`s. One to loop through each item in the `array` and one to iterate through each item in the array that you'll create by `split`ting the string with `,`

Give this a try:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>TITLE</td>
      <td>VALUE 1</td>
      <td>VALUE 2</td>
      <td>VALUE 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of array">
      <td *ngFor="let column of row.split(',')">
        {{ column }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bp8qve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.