# Angular parse response from database

Tags: angularjs, database, response

I have response from database:

```
{"status":"success","message":"Data selected from database","data":[{"id":1171,"sku":0,"word_one":"one word","description":"","word_two":"two word","mrp":0,"lang_one":"en","image":"","lang_two":"en","status":"Active","category":"[{\"text\":\"someone\"},{\"text\":\"sometwo\"}]","UserID":188},
...

{"id":1170,"sku":0,"word_one":"something","description":"","word_two":"some two","mrp":0,"lang_one":"en","image":"","lang_two":"en","status":"Active","category":"[{\"text\":\"ever\"},{\"text\":\"never\"}]","UserID":188}]}
```

Before I make post: `angular.toJson($scope.category);`

How I can show `category` something like this

```
{{category}} = someone, sometwo ?
```

Because actually I have string :

```
[{"text":"someone"},{"text":"sometwo"}]
[{"text":"ever"},{"text":"never"}]
```

...

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: How I can show category something like this
{{category}} = someone, sometwo ?

Comment: I like this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/31805688/977593

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below parsing to achieve what you want. Suppose json is the variable received from database.

```
var json = {"status":"success","message":"Data selected from database","data":[{"id":1171,"sku":0,"word_one":"one word","description":"","word_two":"two word","mrp":0,"lang_one":"en","image":"","lang_two":"en","status":"Active","category":"[{\"text\":\"someone\"},{\"text\":\"sometwo\"}]","UserID":188}]};
var data = json.data[0].category;
var jsonArray = JSON.parse(data);
var category = "";
jsonArray.map(function(obj, i ) {
    if(i != 0) {
      category += ",";
    }
    category += obj.text; 
});
console.log(category)
```

At the end , You attach category to $scope.category.

Comment: I can't get acces to "category" because it is string received from datebase. Maybe I must convert "category" again to array?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
Maybe because I can't acces to category in this way: var data = json.category;
var json in this case looks like:
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
7:Object
8:Object
length:9
__proto__:Array[0]

Comment: How does ur JSON object look like ? can u post it here

Comment: [Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
    $$hashKey: "object:82"
    UserID: 188
    category: "[{"text":"sometext"},{"text":"someword"}]"
    description: ""
    id: 1170
    image: ""
    lang_one: "en"
    lang_two: "en"
    mrp: 0
    sku: 0
    status: "Active"
    word_one: "one some"
    word_two: "two some"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 9
    __proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 . This issue comes if the Json what you have is not a proper json . Please check whether u r getting a proper json from backend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124010/discussion-between-sasank-sunkavalli-and-andrzej).

Comment: When I send data to mysql from input I do this:
product.category = angular.toJson($scope.categorys);

In php side I have:

$app->get('/products', function() { 
    global $db;
    $rows = $db->select("products","id,sku,word_one,description,word_two,mrp,lang_one,image,lang_two,status,category,UserID",array('UserID' => $_SESSION['uid']));
    echoResponse(200, $rows);
});

Comment: Thanks! You helped me!

Answer (score 0):

This work:

```
        var parsed = JSON.parse($scope.c.category);
        var arr = [];
        for(var x in parsed){
          arr.push(parsed[x]);
        }
        $scope.c.category = arr;
```