# Using ng-if inside ng-bind Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in tags">
   {{tag + "," }}
</span>
```

I need to remove `,` after the last element. I know `ng-if="$last"` can solve the problem. But, as I don't have any parent element for `{{tag}}` I can't use `ng-if` so, just need some work around.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11541161/4053389) answer

Comment: @abpatil charm !! You saved my day :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a ternary together with `()` in order to prevent weird outcome:

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in tags">
   {{tag + ($last ? "" : ",")}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary operator within the mustache like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in tags">
   {{tag + $last ? "" : "," }}
</span>
```

Cheers!

*EDIT*: Had written down the answer in a hurry before- correcting the mistake above:

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in tags">
   {{tag}}{{$last ? "" : ","}}
</span>
```

or

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in tags">
   {{tag + ($last ? "" : ",")}}
</span>
```