# Change colour of text within angular array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

We have some nested data which we are are displaying in a table.

One of the table cells is the contents of an array which is turned into a single string using the answer to this question [Using comma as list separator with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540157/using-comma-as-list-separator-with-angularjs)

One request we've had is to colour the elements of the array based. The array would be something like:

```
[{name: "bob", color: red}, {name: "alice", color: green}]
```

However, I can't seem to find a way of applying the colour to the text as part of the ng-repeat.

I'm aware one option is to pre-process the array and replace the *names* with  elements.

Comment: it's hard to really offer a solution based on what you have presented here so far, but have you tried `ng-class` or `ng-style`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to apply the color is to use ng-style:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("myController", myController)

function myController() {
  this.data = [{ name: "Bob", color: "red" }, { name: "Alice", color: "green"}];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in ctrl.data" ng-style="{ color: person.color }">{{person.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd failed to find any example with ng-repeat and ng-style used together. All I'd found was style applied after the fact.