# Angular js remove comma , ] , " from a data before it appears on the table

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

Is there a way we can filter the data when it already appears on the table , just wanted to ask how we can remove " ] from interviewer and applicant so that it will not appear based on what is on the screenshot . I want the " and ] remove when it appears on the table. By the way interviewer and applicant is an array , is there a way that when this data appear on the table " " and [ ] will be remove or not appear.

## Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc19a.jpg

## html

```
<tr ng-repeat="int in main.records.interviews.data track by $index">
                    <td align="center" ng-bind="int.interviewer || 'Unititled'"></td>


 <td align="center" align="center" ng-bind="int.location || 'Unititled'"></div></td>
                <td align="center" ng-bind="int.scheduled_date"></td>
                <td   align="center" ng-bind="int.applicant"></td>
                <td align="center">
```

## response data

```
[  
   {  
      id:5,
      company:6,
      interviewer:[  
         "asd"
      ],
      applicant:[  
         "helloworld@gmail.com",
         "not@gmail.com"
      ],
      scheduled_date:"2019-03-02",
      …
   }
]
```

Comment: If `interviewer` only contains one element then replace `ng-bind="int.interviewer || 'Unititled'"` with `ng-bind="int.interviewer[0] || 'Unititled'"`. Otherwise, use `ng-repeat` to show them all

Comment: Ahh okay , how about on array with multiple values like applicant?

Comment: You can use `ng-repeat`: `<td   align="center"><span ng-repeat="apl in int.aplicant">{{ apl }}</span></td>`

Comment: Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11540157/9867451)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help! :D

Comment: Bro i wanted to ask how are we going to seperate comma on applicant cause applicant has multiple value , how we gonna separate comma to each value when it appears on table?

Comment: cause what happened is that the ouput is this helloworld@gmail.comnot@gmail.com instead of helloworld@gmail.com , not@gmail.com

Comment: Did you read the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11540157/9867451) in my third comment, it shows precisily how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should print values of array instead of array itself.

```
<td align="center" ng-bind="int.interviewer.join(', ') || 'Unititled'"></td>
```