# Space disabled on concatenation

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have an array which looks like this

```
skills: [
        "HTML5",
        "CSS3",
        "SCSS",
        "Bootstrap",
        "JavaScript",
        "Vue.js",
        "PHP",
        "MySQL",
        "Symfony"
      ]
```

And in my template I'm doing something like

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(skill,index) of skills" :key="index">{{ skill + ', '}}</li>
</ul>
```

But what I get is

```
HTML5,CSS3,SCSS,Bootstrap,JavaScript,Vue.js,PHP,MySQL,Symfony,
```

How do I able the spaces?

Btw is there a better way to concatenate the elements of my array? I first used join() like that

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(skill,index) of skills.join(', ')" :key="index">{{ skill }}</li>
</ul>
```

But not only the spaces are still disabled but it returns every character of my elements, I don't know why

Like

```
<ul data-v-c226fde6="">
<li data-v-c226fde6="">H</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">T</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">M</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">L</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">5</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">,</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6=""> </li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">C</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">S</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">S</li>
<li data-v-c226fde6="">3</li>
...
```

EDIT: otherwise what I could just do is

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(skill,index) of skills" :key="index">{{ skill + ','}}</li>
</ul>
```

And then adding some padding-right to the li but I don't know if it's good practice + I don't know how I would remove the comma after the last element

Comment: why are you using commas with `li`? if you want the commas try `<li v-for....>{{ skill }}, </li>`

Comment: is it a must to use `<ul><li></li></ul>`? why dont just `<div>{{skills.join(", ")}}</div>`

Comment: @depperm What's wrong with commas lol? And the commas are not the problem, the problem is that I want a space after each of those (like HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap...) and it's not working, the spaces are like disabled

Comment: @HongJian Well it's not a must but I think it's more semantic since this is a **list** of my skills. Gonna try if it works with a div tho

Comment: there is no problem with commas, just the use of commas with `li` seems pointless as `li` items are often/commonly already separated by a new line and frequently with bullet points

Comment: @depperm Yeah but here I want to display an inline list so no new line or bullet points, just commas

Answer (score 0):

Inside html template such as `li` you have to specify space characters using `&nbsp;`;

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(skill,index) of skills" :key="index">{{ skill + ','}}&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

also checkout https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp
to learn more about HTML entities

Answer (score 0):

With that code you will get a list of `<li></li>` elements with each skill looking like this:

```
<li>HTML5,</li><li>CSS3,</li><li>...
```

just add a class or even a style with a margin to the right to add a little space between the elements either:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(skill,index) of skills" style="margin-right: 5px" :key="index">{{ skill }}</li>
</ul>
```

better:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(skill,index) of skills" class="class-with-some-margin-right" :key="index">{{ skill }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `', '` after each item using CSS like so:

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    skills: ["HTML5", "CSS3", "SCSS", "Bootstrap", "JavaScript",
             "Vue.js", "PHP", "MySQL", "Symfony", ]
  }
})
```

```css
/* styling help: 
  Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517220/
  A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517228/7505395 */

#example-1 {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

#example-1 li {
  display: inline;
}

#example-1 li:after {
  content: ", ";
}

#example-1 li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="(sk, idx) in skills" :key="idx">{{ sk }}</li>
</ul>
```

This answer incorporates it into Vue, for the pure css answer, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517228/7505395).

As always you can also combine normal text inside Vues {{}} like so : `{{ skill + ', ' }}` - not sure if thats helpfull though as it applies to all replacement and you end up having a trailing `,`

Comment: It works for removing the comma to the last child and that's cool BUT... space still not working :( Is it Vue disabling them? I'm using vue-loader with webpack and stuff maybe it has something to do

Comment: @Nel try again, make sure `<li v-for="(sk, idx) in skills" :key="idx">{{ sk }}</li>` is one line no linebreaks in it. Also make sure that comme + space are given inside the CSS like done above

Comment: I swear that's what I did lol. But now that I know how to remove the comma to the last child I could just use your css + some right padding and that's it I get what I want